# Memcache (northscale) socket pool question for Enyim

Tags: exception, memcached, pool, enyim

I'm using Northscale 1.0.0 and need a little help getting it to limp along for long enough to upgrade to the new version. I'm using C# and ASP.NET to work with it using the Enyim libraries. I currently suspect that the application does not have enough connections per the socketPool setting in my app.config. I also noted that the previous developer's code simply treats ANY exception from an attempted Get call to MemCache as if the item isn't in the cache, which (I believe) may be resulting in periodic spikes in calls to the database when the pool gets starved. We've been having oddball load spikes that don't seem to have any relation to server load. I suspect that he is not correctly managing the lifecycle on the connections to Northscale and that we are periodically experiencing starvation in the socket pool as a result, but I'm unable to prove it.

Is there a specific exception I should be looking for when I call the Get method to retrieve items from cache? I'm not really seeing much in the docs that gives me sufficient information on this. Anybody have any sample code on this? I'd even accept java or php code, as I think the .NET libraries were probably based on one of those anyway.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Will

Answer (score 0):

If you have made the connection correctly to the membase server(formerly Northscale) typically you only get an exception on 'get' when it's not a hit.